# get value checkbox when click the button to create a table

Tags: javascript, yii2

if have 2 checkbox list and 1 table. then the code at the bottom there are javascript

```
<div class="mutiple-array-form">
    <form id="sampleTbl">
        <input type="checkbox" name="person" value="Ristha:30">Ristha - 30</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="person" value="Kinen:35">Kinen - 35</input> 
    </form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::button('Create',['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'id' => 'idOfButton']) ?>
    </div>
    <table id="sampleTbl", class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr id="myRow">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>william</td>
                <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Muli</td>
                <td>25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sukoco</td>
                <td>29</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Below my from code, this my Javascript code:

```
<?php  
    $script = <<< JS
        $('#idOfButton').click(function(){
            ?????????????????
        });
    JS;
    $this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

I don't know how to fill javascript to set my value checkbox to create a table when i click button?

Comment: Use `$('[name="person"]:checked').val()`

Comment: i don't know how to split value checkbox to send in the for each row name and row age. can't you write full javascript code for this problem?

Comment: `var selected = {}; $('[name="person"]:checked').each(function() { selected[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val(); });`

Comment: how to get value age? how to split it

Comment: Dear Stfvns, use `split`, CODE: `var selected = {}; $('[name="person"]:checked').each(function() { selected[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val().split(':')[1]; });`

Comment: Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/bo7dzv5c/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this inside button click:

```
$('[name="person"]:checked').each(function () {
        var arr = $(this).val().split(':');
        $('#sampleTbl tbody').append('<tr><td>' + arr[0] + '</td><td>' + arr[1] + '</td></tr>');
    });
```